# \??\C:\ Question Marks in Paths

Tags: windows, memory

I often come across paths similar to `\??\C:\Windows` when looking in memory.  I have been unable to understand why the double '`?`' is appended to some paths. My google-fu is failing me with the ability to find a reason for the double '`?`'.Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Windows Internals, Part 1 (6th Edition)](http://a.co/7DtLqTA) --

> All object-manager functions related to namespace management are aware
>   of the instanced directories and participate in providing the illusion
>   that all sessions use the same namespace. Windows subsystem DLLs
>   prefix names passed by Windows applications that reference objects in
>   \DosDevices with *\??* (for example, C:\Windows becomes \??\C:\Windows).
>   When the object manager sees the special \?? prefix, the steps it
>   takes depends on the version of Windows, but it always relies on a
>   field named *DeviceMap* in the executive process object (EPROCESS, which
>   is described further in Chapter 5) that points to a data structure
>   shared by other processes in the same session.
>
> The *DosDevicesDirectory* field of the *DeviceMap* structure points at the
>   object manager directory that represents the process’ local
>   \DosDevices. When the object manager sees a reference to \??, it
>   locates the process’ local \DosDevices by using the
>   *DosDevicesDirectory* field of the *DeviceMap*. If the object manager
>   doesn’t find the object in that directory, it checks the *DeviceMap*
>   field of the directory object. If it’s valid, it looks for the object
>   in the directory pointed to by the *GlobalDosDevicesDirectory* field of
>   the *DeviceMap* structure, which is always \Global??.

Comment: -1 this does not answer the question and should not be the accepted answer. OP asked about `\??\` and not `\\?\`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I wasn't able to delete my answer because it was already marked as accepted, but I edited it to reflect the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

I have been searching for an answer to this question for a while and I know this question is years old but on the off chance someone else comes across this question I will leave my response here.

The above answer is referring to non-canonicalized device paths where as you are asking about `\??\` not `\\?\` there may only be a small difference in the question but the answer is completely different.

`\??` is a "fake" prefix which refers to per-user Dos devices, so here is an image that will hopefully help you understand what the process is: [image]

Some definitions that may help you understand:

- \Device - Default location for kernel driver Device Objects
- \GLOBAL?? - System location for symbolic links to devices including drive letters
- \BaseNamedObjects - System location for named resources
- \Sessions\X - Directory for the login session X
- \Session\0\DosDevices -
  Directory for the “Dos Devices” for each logged in  user.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer

Comment: Why's the "Blah\..\" there in the orange box?